# How to form a set from 4 sets with the given property?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, combinations

*Hi, this question is related to Combinatorics. If there is anything I can improve with my question, please let me know.*

**Problem:** Let us suppose  we have $4$ sets $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4$ having $a,b,c,d$ elements. All elements in each $S_i$ are distinct for $1\leq i\leq 4$.
We need to form a set $S$ from  the elements of $S_i;1\leq i\leq 4$ with the following property:

$S$  must contain $a-1$ elements of $S_1$, $b-1$ elements of $S_2$, $c-1$ elements of $S_3$ and $d-1$ elements of $S_4$.

Find the number of ways to form $S$ if $S$ has

1. $a+b+c+d-3$ elements.
2. $a+b+c+d-2$ elements.

**My try:**
*Method 1:* Note that $a+b+c+d-3=(a-1)+(b-1)+(c-1)+(d-1)+1$.
We first choose  $a-1$ elements from $S_1$ in $\binom{a}{a-1}=a$ ways,then choose  $b-1$ elements from $S_2$ in $\binom{b}{b-1}=b$ ways,
then choose  $c-1$ elements from $S_3$ in $\binom{c}{c-1}=c$ ways
and finally choose  $d-1$ elements from $S_4$ in $\binom{d}{d-1}=d$ ways.
We now need to choose $1$ remaining  element of $S$ from $\bigcup_{i=1}^4 S_i$.
Now $1$ remaining  element of $S$ from $\bigcup_{i=1}^4 S_i$ can be chosen in $\binom{4}{1}=4$ ways.
So total number of ways= $4\times a\times b\times c\times d$.

*Method 2:* We choose $a$ elements from $S_1$, $b-1$ from $S_2$, $c-1$ from $S_3$, $d-1$ from $S_4$.
Note that $a$ elements can be chosen from $S_1$ in $\binom{a}{a}=1$ way,then choose  $b-1$ elements from $S_2$ in $\binom{b}{b-1}=b$ ways,
then choose  $c-1$ elements from $S_3$ in $\binom{c}{c-1}=c$ ways
and finally choose  $d-1$ elements from $S_4$ in $\binom{d}{d-1}=d$ way.
Thus it becomes $b\times c\times d$ ways.

Similarly  we can choose $a-1$ elements from $S_1$, $b$ from $S_2$, $c-1$ from $S_3$, $d-1$ from $S_4$.
Thus it becomes $a\times c\times d$ ways. Similarly  we can choose $a-1$ elements from $S_1$, $b-1$ from $S_2$, $c$ from $S_3$, $d-1$ from $S_4$. Thus it becomes $a\times b\times d$ ways.

So total ways= $bcd+acd+abd+abc.$

**I have 3 questions:**

1. Why are the answers in two methods coming different?
2. I feel *Method 2* gives the correct answer but the method is very lengthy and cumbersome and can't be extended. Is it possible to write it in a short and elegant way?
3. How to do the second part of the question where $S$ must have $(a-1)+(b-1)+(c-1)+(d-1)+2$ elements? How to extend *Method 1* or *Method 2* here?

*I am looking for some help from all the experts out here. Waiting for your responses.*

Comment: Doesn't the question state that $S$ must contain $a-1$ elements from $S_1$? So why did you choose $a$ elements from $S_1$?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Sometimes, the phrase “must contain $a-1$ items…” means “must contain **at least** $a-1$ items…”.  It is an unfortunate ambiguity in English, which often leads to confusion in the wordings of math questions.

Comment: @MikeEarnest; I second that

Comment: Dear @Ritam_Dasgupta; I understand your query, I hope Mike's justification helps you.

Comment: @Mike Earnest, OK, I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method 2 is correct. Method 1 overcounts, because in the event that you end up using all $a$ elements of $S_1$, it distinguishes between the $a-1$ originally chosen elements and the element added later. But all ways to choose $a-1$ elements and then add the last one are equivalent (they all give you the whole of $S_1$).

To answer your final question, in part 2 instead of having three sets with one element missing and one full, you have two sets with one element missing and two full. The number of ways to choose $a-1$ elements from $S_1$, $b-1$ from $S_2$, and all the rest is $ab$, so you need all permutations of this, i.e. $ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd$.

The issue with extending is really one of notation. It is cumbersome because you have $a$ elements in $S_1$, $b$ in $S_2$, etc., instead of the more natural $a_1$ in $S_1$, $a_2$ in $S_2$, etc. With this notation your first expression would become
$\sum_{i,j,k\text{ distinct}}a_ia_ja_k$ and your second $\sum_{i,j\text{ distinct}}a_ia_j$.

Comment: Yes I also felt so which I have mentioned in my question. However I would be glad if you take a note of all my #3 questions

Comment: @Olivia have added some thoughts on the other questions.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir for your time. +1 for you from my side.